# Enumerable select to set attribute and return object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enumeration

I need to iterate over an array, set an attribute, and return the modified objects.

Obviously, `map` can be used like so:

```
items.map do |item|
   item.foo = bar
   item
end
```

But it seems bulky for such simple operation.

Using `select` is much more simple.

```
items.select { |item| item.foo = bar }
```

However, I've only used `select` to test a condition. In this scenario, a condition is not really being tested during iteration, but it still returning true upon successfully setting the attribute.

Is this an acceptable way to use `select` or is it a hack?

Comment: It is acceptable: you litteraly select the `items` that can have `foo` updated with `bar` value.

Comment: IMO the map is much more clear then select. select is something similar to the find_all method, it doesn't implied a modification on the iterated item.